# Plotting a special 2d set in Mathematica

Tags: plotting

I have a set $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ with the following description:
$$
S=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{2}\mid0\leq x^{\top}y\leq1,\;\forall y\in S\}.
$$
In other words, if $x$ and $y$ are points in $S$, then we have
$0\leq x^{\top}y\leq1$. Is there a way to plot such a set in Mathematica?

Comment: An explicit example in copy-pastable format would be useful.

Comment: It is of the form: `{ (w,x) :  0 <= w*y+x*z <= 1, y^2 + z^2 <= 1, w^2 + x^2 <=1}`

Comment: And `y` and `z` are...?

Comment: `(y,z)` is another point in the set $S$, i.e, the definition of the set says that inner product between any two points `(w,x)` and `(y,z)` in the set $S$ is between 0 and 1.

Comment: The result should be any 1/4 Disk, that is, `With[{θ = RandomReal[{0, 2 π}]}, 
 Graphics[Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {θ, θ + π/2}], 
  Axes -> True, PlotRange -> 1]]`

Answer (score 6):

Consider 0<=x.y<=1. As x and y may be identical, it follows that Norm[x]<=1 and Norm[y]<=1. Therefore S must be inside the unit circle. Further, as 0<= x.y, the angle phi between x and y must be -Pi/4<=phi<= Pi/4.

Therefore, you can choose some point: p on the unit circle, and S is a quorter of a unit disc where p is the middle of the quarter circle. E.g.:

```
p = {Cos[30 Degree],Sin[30 Degree]]};
phi = ArcTan @@ p
Graphics[Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {phi - Pi/4, phi + Pi/4}], Axes -> True]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: But `{Cos[135 Degree], Sin[135 Degree]} . {Cos[-45 Degree], 
   Sin[-45 Degree]} < 0`

Comment: I see, okay this is an issue then...

Comment: @cvmt Yes you are right, it should of course  read phi +/- Pi/4 and not Pi/2. I corrected it.

Answer (score 6):

- The result should be any 1/4 `Disk`.
- Since $\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}\geq 0$ means that the angle between $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ is less then `π/2`.

```
θ = RandomReal[{0, 2  π}];
reg = Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {θ, θ + π/2}];
{x, y} = RandomPoint[reg];
{u, v} = RandomPoint[reg];
Graphics[{reg, Red, Arrow[{{0, 0}, {x, y}}], 
  Arrow[{{0, 0}, {u, v}}]}]
0 <= {x, y} . {u, v} <= 1
```

> `True`.

[image]